# Add extra form fields when one field has certain value in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I have a storage entity (lager) and storage type entity (lagertype).
The storage has a storage number field. Based on the type it can have up to 3 fields.

I have troubles setting up the form in a way that extra fields will be added when choosing a certain storage type.

Here is the entity for storage (lager)

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lager_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $lagerId;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lager_name", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
 */
private $lagerName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lager_description", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $lagerDescription;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lager_id_number", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
 */
private $lagerIdNumber;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lager_address_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $lagerAddressId;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lager_timestamp", type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"default"="current_timestamp()"})
 */
private $lagerTimestamp = 'current_timestamp()';

/**
 * @var \LagerType
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="LagerType")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lager_lager_type_id", referencedColumnName="lager_type_id")
 * })
 */
private $lagerLagerType;
```

Here is the form

```
class LagerFormType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @var LagerTypeRepository
     */
    private $lagerTypeRepository;


    /**
     * KundeArtikelFormType constructor.
     * @param ArtikelRepository $artikelRepository
     */
    public function __construct(LagerTypeRepository $lagerTypeRepository)
    {
        $this->lagerTypeRepository = $lagerTypeRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('lagerName', null,
                ['label' => false, 'attr' => ['pattern' => '[A-Za-z0-9-_ ]+', 'maxlength' => 255]])
            ->add('lagerDescription', null,
                ['label' => false, 'attr' => ['pattern' => '[A-Za-z0-9-_ ]+', 'maxlength' => 255]])
            ->add('lagerLagerType', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $this->lagerTypeRepository->getAllAvailableLagerType(),
                'label' => false,
            ])
            ->add('lagerIdNumber', null,
                ['label' => false, 'attr' => ['pattern' => '[A-Za-z0-9-_ ]+', 'maxlength' => 255]])
            ->add('lagerAddressId', IntegerType::class,
                ['label' => false, 'attr' => ['min' => 1, 'max' => 3]])
            ->add('Speichern', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'btn--red']
            ]);

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $data = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            $lagerLagerType = $data->getlagerLagerType();
            var_dump($lagerLagerType);
            if ($lagerLagerType == 1) {
                $form->add('lagerIdNumber2', null,
                    ['label' => false, 'attr' => ['pattern' => '[A-Za-z0-9-_ ]+', 'maxlength' => 255]]);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Lager::class,
            'mapped' => false]);
    }
}
```

Instead of using entity type I use choice type in the form and create an array inside the repository that only uses the name and the id of the lager type. I looked up the symfony tutorial and tried for hours but not understanding it fully. My take on this is listening to any changes in the form such as the storage type get its value and if value is equal 1 for instance add another field to it.

When I debugged it this-> $data = $event->getData(); returns null

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For reasons that I have never been clear on, PRE_SET_DATA sometimes gets fired twice.  If $data === null then just return.  The second time your listener is called it should have data in it.  If you look closely you see this in [the example](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#adding-an-event-listener-to-a-form-class).

Comment: The experiences I had with the form events is this: PRE_SET_DATA is fired, when controller::createForm($formType[, $presetData]) is called with a second parameter. What people usually want is a form handler that reacts to user input, i.e. when FormInterface::handleRequest($request) is called, which is the PRE_SUBMIT or SUBMIT event. (depending on which kind of data they want to interact with). (this will only add the form field in the browser after submission of the form, so some ajax magic might be needed)